# flutter nested navigation with BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, nested, flutter-getx, navigator, bottom-navigation-bar

I ran into the problem that if there is another page in the stack under the HomeScreen page, then when I go back (swipe on ios) from the nested page, I am transferred to the HS page, and not to the HomeScreen page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const NestedNavigation());
}

class NestedNavigation extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedNavigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Nested Navigation - BNB',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      getPages: <GetPage>[
        GetPage(name: '/settings', page: () => const SettingsWrapper(), fullscreenDialog: true),
        GetPage(name: '/home', page: () => const HomeScreen()),
        GetPage(name: '/', page: () => const HS()),
      ],
      initialRoute: '/',
      initialBinding: BindingsBuilder.put(() => HomeController()),
    );
  }
}

class HS extends StatelessWidget {
  const HS({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("nested test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){Get.toNamed('/home');},
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: controller.state.value == HomeState.home ? 0 : 1,
            onTap: (index) => index == 0
                ? controller.selectHome()
                : controller.selectSettings(),
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
            ],
          ),
          body: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              switch (controller.state.value) {
                case HomeState.home:
                  return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar')),
                    body: const Center(child: Text('Home')),
                  );
                case HomeState.settings:
                  return const SettingsWrapper();
              }
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}

enum HomeState { home, settings }

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  final state = HomeState.home.obs;

  void selectHome() => state.value = HomeState.home;

  Future<void> selectSettings() async {
    if (state.value == HomeState.settings) {
      try {
        await Get.keys[SettingsNavigation.id]!.currentState!.maybePop();
      } catch (e) {
        // error
      }
    }
    state.value = HomeState.settings;
  }

  void navigateToSettingsDialog() {
    Get.toNamed(SettingsNavigation.dialog, id: SettingsNavigation.id);
  }
}

class SettingsNavigation {
  SettingsNavigation._();

  static const id = 0;

  static const settings = '/settings';
  static const dialog = '/dialog';
}
class SettingsWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<HomeController>();

    return Navigator(
      key: Get.nestedKey(SettingsNavigation.id),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == SettingsNavigation.dialog) {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: SettingsNavigation.dialog,
            page: () => const SettingsScreen(id: SettingsNavigation.id, first: false),
          );
        } else {
          return GetPageRoute(
            routeName: SettingsNavigation.settings,
            page: () => const SettingsScreen(id: SettingsNavigation.id, first: true),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final int? id;
  final bool first;

  const SettingsScreen({Key? key, this.id, required this.first})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (first) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Settings'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () =>
              Get.toNamed(SettingsNavigation.dialog, id: SettingsNavigation.id),
          child: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
        ),
        body: const Center(child: Text('Main Settings')),
      );
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          title: const Text('Detail'),
        ),
        body: const Center(child: Text('Detail Settings')),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

if you remove the HS page from the stack by making the transition offAndToNamed from it, then everything works as expected, but in my example, the page with the BottomNavigationBar is not the first